# Run CHKDSK on Disk other than disk 0?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk, bad-sectors

I have three disks on my system, and one is a laptop disk that may be bad in a SATA enclosure hooked by USB 2.  It is disk 1 in Windows (of disk 0, disk 1, and disk 2).  I would love to run `CHKDSK` on it but it seems to be only able to run on the primary disk or a drive letter.

The drive isn't showing up in Computer, because either is is bad or because the drive letters are the same as the primary disk (C: and D:).

Linux couldn't find disk either, and `gparted` showed IO error on the device.

I'm trying to do all I can before either taking it to a professional or just tossing it.

Comment: The hard drive might be fine, the enclosure might be the problem, remove it from the enclosure before you toss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible for the drive letters to be "the same" because they are assigned by Windows, not permanently kept somewhere on disk; it would simply use `E:` and `F:`, for example. If it does not, try assigning a new one using `diskmgmt.msc` or `mountvol`. (Don't forget that disks can be mounted on folders, not just on diskletters; e.g. `C:\Disks\Backup`.)

However, as you said, Linux also reports I/O errors on the disk, so this shows that the problem is *not* with "drive letters" but at a lower level.

It does not make much sense to run `chkdsk` on a volume that cannot be mounted, as the primary purpose of `chkdsk` is to check a *filesystem* for consistency, and any filesystem that Windows does not recognize is beyond `chkdsk`'s help.